# using python how to calculate quartile/percentile & gives criteria for create a new column for analysis?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, percentile

I have data  like this :

```
Village     Workers
Takali      127
Dhokari     84
Aagar       10
Gardhani    122
Khanapur    65
Ambikanagar 45
Pi.Khand    120
Pangri      105
Dhagewadi   32
Sherewadi   34
Shindwad    42
```

I want to create a new column, where I have to define Small, Medium and Large level by using percentile method.

For example : using excel command  =PERCENTILE(Data numbers, 1/3) will be gives 43,

and =PERCENTILE(Data numbers, 2/3) will be gives 98 .

so, I want to use 1/3 & 2/3 percentile in python,

and I want to do criteria like

If Workers  < = 1/3 percentile value   will be define as Small

If Workers   < =2/3 Percentile value will be define as Medium

IF  Workers  > 2/3 Percentile value will be define as Large

I don't know how to do this in python, I know  using excel.

[image]

[image]

Can you please help me how to solve this problem in python ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`qcut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.qcut.html), only is necessary change order of levels:

```
import pandas as pd 

df['level'] = pd.qcut(df['Workers'], 3, ['Small','Medium','Large'])
print (df)
        Village  Workers   level
0        Takali      127   Large
1       Dhokari       84  Medium
2         Aagar       10   Small
3      Gardhani      122   Large
4      Khanapur       65  Medium
5   Ambikanagar       45  Medium
6      Pi.Khand      120   Large
7        Pangri      105   Large
8     Dhagewadi       32   Small
9     Sherewadi       34   Small
10     Shindwad       42   Small
```

Comment: ,its gives me error :   AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'qcut'

Comment: It is typo, `pd` not `df`

Comment: I am not get it where is typo? :(

Comment: Sorry, `pd.qcut` not `df.qcut`

Comment: ,thanks again for helps :) got it . import pandas as pd .. then pd we can use

Comment: Yes, exactly. I remove it, because all pandas code need it ;)

Comment: 3 minutes remaining for accept answer, i will accept it within 3min

Comment: qcut is for 1/3 & 2/3 percentile we use ?